# Where does the downloaded file get stored while executing a script in bamboo?

Tags: java, automated-tests, bitbucket, bamboo, cicd

I am new to automation testing.
I have a script which i am currently running in eclipse. The scenario of the script is that it downloads a file from one website and then it will upload the same downloaded file to another website. For uploading the downloaded file, i gave the path of the file as
c:/user/downloads
and it is working fine if i run in eclipse.
So my actual ambiguity is, if i push the code into bitbucket and if i schedule a job in bamboo, where does the downloaded file get stored? Which path should i give in the script if i have to run this script in bamboo?

Comment: just add simple commands in the bamboo scripts to determine `pwd`, `ls -l`

Answer (score 0):

When Bamboo runs script it uses working directory, separate for every job. You can get location of this folder at ${bamboo_build_working_directory} or %bamboo_build_working_directory%, see more details at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-variables-289277087.html